# react mui autoComplete.Network in this component works not as I want

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to load selections by network when the input changes.
But sometimes the network happens very late. And the selections wasn't set by last network.

For example.If there are 5 inputs, [t, te, tes, test, tes], the options are always by input 'test' not tes even the last input is tes.

And the time line maybe like this

[t 5ms] [te 10 ms] [tes 15ms] [test 20ms] [tes 3s](join the queue very late)

I'm writing kotlin js, and code are in company network so not copiable.But some fake code is below

```
let state = useState(model) //options are a field of model

onInputChange = (text)=> {
     callNetwork((result)=>{
          state = calculate(result)
     })
}
```